# prove that this series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

if $ 0\le a_n \le 1$ and if $ 0\le x < 1$, 
then prove that $∑a_nx^n$ for n=0,1,2,... converges.

and that its sum is not greater than $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

do I  need to use comparison test here? how should I work on this question? I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Do you how to sum $\sum x^{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

it follows from

$∑a_nx^n\leq∑x^{n}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ where I used the fact that $a_{n}\leq 1$ in the first step and the sum for geometrycal series in the second, because $0<x<1$.

Comment: Perhaps better to write inequalities of partial sums, then take limits.